# I have a weights variable and I need to create cross tabulations for a chord diagram

Tags: r, weighted, two-way

I have a dataset with over 15,000 observations. I've dropped all variables but three (3).
One is the individual's origin `or`, the other is the individual's destination `dest`, and the third is weight of that individual `wgt`.

Origin and destination are categorical variables.

The weights I have are used as `analytic weights` in Stata. However, Stata can't handle the number of columns I generate when making tables. R generates them with ease. However, I can't figure out how to apply weights into the generated table.

I tried using `wtd.tables()`, but the following error appears.

```css
wtd.table(NonHSGrad$b206reg, NonHSGrad$c305reg, weights=NonHSGrad$ind_wgts)

Error in proxy[, ..., drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

When I use only the `table()`, this comes out:

```css
 table(NonHSGrad$b206reg, NonHSGrad$c305reg)
    
       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
  1  285  38  20   8   6   3   1   2   0   1   0  10  38  46   0   2  14
  2   32 312  26   3   1   0   2   1   1   0   1   1  22  51   0   0   8
  3   17  35 325  12  12   2   3   7   0   2   3   5  52  13   1   1  25
  4    3   5  27 224  19   5   2  10   1   1   1   2  51   4   0   3  35
  5    4   9  44  81 778   6   7  22   1   4   5   5 155   5   0   5  47
  6    4   5  22  21  10 547  24  12  32  21  32  81  86   5   3  15  58
  7    5   4  12  17  20  21 558  20  31  99  93  33  59   1   3  67  15
  8    8   9  41  49  17  11  24 919   5   8  37  10 151   2   0  52  19
  9    0   1   7   9   1   4  26   5 466  66  19  17  17   2  24  24   7
  10   1   2   3   4   2   3  27   8  41 528  21  17  13   2  11  36   2
  11   3   0   3  10   1   5  11   5   6  17 519  59   7   1   2  49   1
  12   0   1   1   2   0   1   5   2   2  10  39 318  10   0  14  17   1
  13  15   9  26  34  25  21  12  42   2   5   3   5 187   2   1   6  15
  14  14  47   7   5   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   9 475   0   0   0
  15   0   0   3   1   2   2   4   2  22   9   3  60   9   2 342   2   3
  16   0   2   6  10   3   2  11  21   3  33  29   4  34   0   3 404   5
  17   1   1   7  15   2   6   1   2   0   1   1   0  34   0   0   2 463
  99   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   2   0   1
```

I am also going to use the table for a chord diagram to show flows.

Comment: Make a minimal reproducible example, then it's easier to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/9220442

Comment: Thanks! I edited my post just now